# Cannot update the time stamp with @UpdateTimestamp annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

```
@UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name="UPDATE_TIME_STAMP")
    private LocalDateTime updateTimeStamp;

@CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name="POLICY_ISSUE_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime policyIssueDate;
```

Hello i'm new to hibernate I have above fields in both my entity and database. However for my Dao method which i'm accessing it from a SpringBoot controller it not updating the UPDATE_TIME_STAMP field in database while executed query updates with bellow method.

```
@Override
    public int updatePolicyStatus(String status,int policyNumber) {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE Policy p SET POLICY_STATUS=:status where POLICY_NUMBER=:policyNumber");
        query.setParameter("status",status);
        query.setParameter("policyNumber", policyNumber);
        return query.executeUpdate();
    }
```

Also If i try to merge the entity it is trying to update the creationTimeStamp with NULL which is getting failed at the end since i kept my POLICY_ISSUE_DATE as NOT NULL in database.

```
@Override
    public void updatePolicy(Policy policy) {
        entityManager.merge(policy);

    }
```

So i how can avoid NULL value for creationTimeStamp while using merge(policy) and also why it the updateTimeStamp not updating with executeUpdate() .

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below shown annotation into your model/entity class.Can you please check this and let me know whether it works for you or not.In my application,I have used it number of times and it works like butter.Hope it will work for you too.

```
@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "data_update_time")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dataUpdateTime;
```

Comment: Note : You can take LocalDateTime  instead of Date in your case

Answer (score 0):

@sai you can add **@Column(updatable=false)** to your policyIssueDate. So it won't get updated to null while you update the row.